# Allow users to favourite a link, moving it to a specific page of a users logged in area

Tags: hyperlink

I would like help explaining how I can allow users to favourite a link, moving it to a specific page of a users logged in area. I have the external links on a separate page which I would like users to be able to save in a favourites page.

I am unsure of the method or where to begin with this, any help will be very appreciated.

*My site acts as an internet directory which has expands to a new page every time an option is selected, until an external link is offered. I would like a option next to the external link that allows that link to be saved into a favourites section of the users private area.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question well, if you can know the page that is being saved by the user, you can save the external link in a database and associate it with the userID. Then, when a user is in his area of favorites than every link associated with him will be retrieved by de DB and you list them there.

*edit*
Yes, you can add a star or a check box to trigger that storage. If you already have a Database as it seems, it won't be hard ;)

Glad I could help.

Comment: I have updated the post. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: It's better. For example, now I now you are making a site ;) I'm not much into web but I think , **if** I understood your question well, if you can know the page that is being saved by the user, you can save the external link in a database and associate it with the userID. Then, when a user is in his area of favorites than every link associated with him will be retrieved by de DT and you list them there.

Comment: That does makes sense. I could use a check box option next to the link which adds it into a database. this then 'Echoes' in favourites section. I just need someone to help with the coding now :D Thanks.